# Stop Scrolling on fingers up

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

When scrolling on my synaptics touchpad using two-finger-scrolling it continues scrolling after my fingers don't touch the trackpad anymore. When I scroll and try to use a keyboard shortcut immediately afterwards it gets interpreted as a Ctrl-Scroll command, which in case of my web browser annoyingly changes the font size.

How can I make the scrolling stop as soon as I release my fingers from the trackpad?

Answer (score 6):

I've asked the same question on unix stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278923/mousewheel-touchpad-scrolling-in-browsers and what I found out after a little bit of exploration is this:

1) Feature is called "Coasting speed"
2) to disable it you can use:

`xinput --set-prop --type=float "<your device>" "Synaptics Coasting Speed" 0 0`

to list devices you can use:

`xinput list`

Good luck! :-)

Comment: wish I could give 100 upvotes.

Comment: How do I keep the changes after restart?